# How to find the inflection point of $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

With the second derivative, the solution gives logarithm of negative number, but I know the graph and the function changes the concavity.

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}$$

What are the inflection points?

Answer (score 1):

For the second derivative you should get $$\frac{e^x-6 e^{3 x}+e^{5 x}}{(e^{2x}+1)^3}$$ So you need to solve $e^x-6 e^{3 x}+e^{5 x} = 0 \implies 1-6 e^{2 x}+e^{4 x} = 0$. Make the substitution $y = e^{2x}$ to get the equation $$1-6y+y^2 = 0$$ and by the quadratic formula we get $y = 3 \pm 2\sqrt{2}$. Now that we have $y$, we can solve back for $x$. We have $x = \frac{1}{2}\ln(y)$, so two real-valued inflection points.